# Python, String is printed out more than once after for loop, although I have a break

Tags: python, string, loops, csv, for-loop

```
import csv 

def Start():
    query = input("\nWhat is wrong with your mobile device? ").upper().split() 
    keyword = len(query) 

    for i in range(keyword):
        filename = ("Advice.csv")
        with open(filename) as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile) 
            for row in reader:
                if query[i] == row['KEYWORDS']:
                    print(row['ADVICE']) 
Start()
```

I'm trying to get my program to print the, "Unfortunately we could not find..." string once if the user inputs a string with no matched keywords in my text file. However, it keeps printing the same amount of times as the number of words in the users inputted string... I believe this is because I used .split() earlier in my code turning the users input into an array, yet I cannot find a way to fix it. I have tried using 'next' and 'any' with no success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only modify your code structure just a bit and the problem goes away:

```
#I/O
filename = ("Advice.csv")
with open(filename) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

#Initial value of results is 0
results = 0 

#Loop through items
for i in range(keyword):
    for row in reader:
        if query[i] == row['KEYWORDS']:
            print(row['ADVICE']) 
            results += 1 #Increment

if not results:  #This is shorthand for if results == 0
    print("Unfortunately we could not find any advice in our database, we recommend calling your supplier or rephrasing your response.")
```

I have made the following modifications to your code:

1. Create a var `results` which tracks the number of matches. We use this var in the last two lines to find out whether or not to print your string. Of course, you can use a boolean for this and just set it to true when a match is found. However I opted to count the matches, since you might be able to use that information somewhere.
2. Move the I/O outside the loop. This wasn't part of your question, however I included it because it greatly improves performance as you read the file only once, no matter how many keywords the user searches for.

Also, depending on the size of your files, it will likely be beneficial for you to switch around the order of the loops (outer loop is the reader, inner loop is the query), this decreasing the number of iterations.

Even better, you could ditch the double loop entirely like so:

```
if row["KEYWORDS] in query:
    print(row["ADVICE"])
else:
     print("Unfortunately we could not find any advice in our database, we recommend calling your supplier or rephrasing your response.")
```

Of course, this is a general suggestion. I cannot know for sure if it will work since you have not provided enough code. See however if you can make something similar work in your program.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've attempted both methods as you described and they worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should also exit from the outer for loop if you want it to stop from checking:

```
for i in range(keyword):
    get_out = False
    filename = ("Advice.csv")
    with open(filename) as csvfile: #Opens the text file 'Advice.csv' as a csvfile
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile) #Reads the file.
        for row in reader:
            if query[i] == row['KEYWORDS']:
                print(row['ADVICE']) #Prints advice linked to keywords.
            else:
                print("Unfortunately we could not find any advice in our database, we recommend calling your supplier or rephrasing your response.")
                get_out = True
                break
    if get_out:
        break
```

I would also suggest changing the loop order since this way you will open the file once and the processing speed gets faster:

```
filename = ("Advice.csv")
with open(filename) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
    get_out = False
        for i in range(keyword):
            if query[i] == row['KEYWORDS']:
                print(row['ADVICE']) #Prints advice linked to keywords.
            else:
                print("Unfortunately we could not find any advice in our database, we recommend calling your supplier or rephrasing your response.")
                get_out = True
                break
if get_out:
    break
```

I think this can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the help!